# Filtering matched text with spaces in a <td> elemenet

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, filter

I'm trying to filter many literal elements in a repeater that match with a filter text input and jQuery. The structure is mainly like this:

```
<div id="divResults">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>My test text </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Another test </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Further text details </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>More details </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>More about the test details, click here </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The code:

```
if ($("#div > tr").text().search(new RegExp("test", "i")) < 0){
  //hide();
} else {
  //show();
}
```

Everything works great. But the things is when I type "test details" I get all the TD elements that contains the word "test" and "details" but I what I want now is to filter an exact match I mean in my case "test details" would be only the last TD. How can I change this code to filter an exact match?

Comment: @Adam: [`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

Comment: Are you trying to find divs that match that pattern, or are you trying to find a match within that entire tr?

Comment: @DavidThomas lol, wow that's pretty bad. For some reason I thought it was a jQuery function :[. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `indexOf()` with the exact string you're searching for:

```
$('table td').addClass(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('test details') > -1 ? 'matched' : 'unmatched';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Mj6P6/);

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: ..each(.. if ($(this).find('div > tr').text().indexOf(query) < 0) { $(this).hide().removeClass('visible')} else { $(this).show().addClass('visible'); }

Comment: My bad. It works awesome. I didn't realize that my query string was being trimming.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your Regular Expression to match the phrase:

```
new RegExp('^(?=.*?test details).*$', 'i')
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/Mj6P6/2/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Do I need to replace this: new RegExp(query, "i") for this: new RegExp('^(?=.*?' + query + ').*$', 'i') I tried but it's not working. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you post an example of the query you're trying? [http://jsfiddle.net/Mj6P6/3](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj6P6/3/)